# Custom Swift Encoder/Decoder for the Strings Resource Format

Tags: swift, swift4, codable, decodable, encodable

I have been playing around with `Codable` and reading and writing JSON from and to a file. Now I would like to write a custom `Coder` that can read and write iOS `.strings` files. Can anyone help me with this? I found the protocols `Encoder` and `Decoder`, but I have no idea what I should implement here:

```
class StringsEncoder {}

extension StringsEncoder: Encoder {
    var codingPath: [CodingKey?] {
        return []
    }

    var userInfo: [CodingUserInfoKey : Any] {
        return [:]
    }

    func container<Key>(keyedBy type: Key.Type) -> KeyedEncodingContainer<Key> where Key : CodingKey {

    }

    func unkeyedContainer() -> UnkeyedEncodingContainer {

    }

    func singleValueContainer() -> SingleValueEncodingContainer {

    }
}

extension StringsEncoder: Decoder {
    func container<Key>(keyedBy type: Key.Type) throws -> KeyedDecodingContainer<Key> where Key : CodingKey {

    }

    func unkeyedContainer() throws -> UnkeyedDecodingContainer {

    }

    func singleValueContainer() throws -> SingleValueDecodingContainer {

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked into the `Codable` protocols and what they can do? I'm not sure the `.strings` format is a right fit for this — the `Codable` protocols have to support general-purpose formats which have arrays, dictionaries, numbers, null values, etc. `.strings` files don't support any of that... It's a very single-purpose format.

Comment: You probably can, though it seems a bit overkill for the strings format. Check out the [JSONEncoder source](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/SDK/Foundation/JSONEncoder.swift) for example, which is well documented. [swift unboxed](https://swiftunboxed.com/) will have a post similar to what you are looking for soon I think

Comment: I know you want to understand Codable, but on the off-chance you just want to read and write to strings file checkout `String.propertyListFromStringsFileFormat()` and `Dictionary.descriptionInStringsFileFormat`

Comment: mikeash has a really good post about building a custom codable object too: https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2017-07-28-a-binary-coder-for-swift.html

Comment: You might want to look at Swift’s implementation of `JSONEncoder` [here](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/master/Foundation/JSONEncoder.swift). There is probably room for Swift to provide some more support for custom Encoders and Decoders, but for now a good idea is to customize that implementation to suit your requirements.

Comment: Strings files are more like a dictionary, and Codable usually works best with fixed layout data structures.

Comment: Implementation of JSONEncoder has moved [here](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/stdlib/public/Darwin/Foundation/JSONEncoder.swift)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

A bit late to the party here but I feel this might be helpful/informative to others given the question high vote count. (But I *won't* really get into the actual usefulness of such code in practice—please check the comments above for that.)

Unfortunately, given the coding stack flexibility and type-safeness, implementing a new *encoding* and *decoding* solution, for an alternative *external representation*, is far from a trivial task... so let's get started:

## Encoding

Let's start by implementing the **encoding** part for the desired [strings file](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/Strings/Strings.html) external representation. (The necessary types will be introduced in a *top-down* approach.)

Like the standard `JSONEncoder` class we need to introduce a class to expose/drive our new encoding API. Let's call that `StringsEncoder`:

```
/// An object that encodes instances of a data type 
/// as strings following the simple strings file format.
public class StringsEncoder {
    
    /// Returns a strings file-encoded representation of the specified value. 
    public func encode<T: Encodable>(_ value: T) throws -> String {
        let stringsEncoding = StringsEncoding()
        try value.encode(to: stringsEncoding)
        return dotStringsFormat(from: stringsEncoding.data.strings)
    }
    
    private func dotStringsFormat(from strings: [String: String]) -> String {
        var dotStrings = strings.map { "\"\($0)\" = \"\($1)\";" }
        dotStrings.sort()
        dotStrings.insert("/* Generated by StringsEncoder */", at: 0)
        return dotStrings.joined(separator: "\n")
    }
}
```

Next, we need to provide a type (e.g., a `struct`) conforming to the core `Encoder` protocol:

```
fileprivate struct StringsEncoding: Encoder {
    
    /// Stores the actual strings file data during encoding.
    fileprivate final class Data {
        private(set) var strings: [String: String] = [:]
        
        func encode(key codingKey: [CodingKey], value: String) {
            let key = codingKey.map { $0.stringValue }.joined(separator: ".")
            strings[key] = value
        }
    }
    
    fileprivate var data: Data
    
    init(to encodedData: Data = Data()) {
        self.data = encodedData
    }

    var codingPath: [CodingKey] = []
    
    let userInfo: [CodingUserInfoKey : Any] = [:]
    
    func container<Key: CodingKey>(keyedBy type: Key.Type) -> KeyedEncodingContainer<Key> {
        var container = StringsKeyedEncoding<Key>(to: data)
        container.codingPath = codingPath
        return KeyedEncodingContainer(container)
    }
    
    func unkeyedContainer() -> UnkeyedEncodingContainer {
        var container = StringsUnkeyedEncoding(to: data)
        container.codingPath = codingPath
        return container
   }
    
    func singleValueContainer() -> SingleValueEncodingContainer {
        var container = StringsSingleValueEncoding(to: data)
        container.codingPath = codingPath
        return container
    }
}
```

Finally, we need to handle all 3 *encoding containers* types:

- `KeyedEncodingContainer`
- `UnkeyedEncodingContainer`
- `SingleValueEncodingContainer`

```
fileprivate struct StringsKeyedEncoding<Key: CodingKey>: KeyedEncodingContainerProtocol {

    private let data: StringsEncoding.Data
    
    init(to data: StringsEncoding.Data) {
        self.data = data
    }
    
    var codingPath: [CodingKey] = []
    
    mutating func encodeNil(forKey key: Key) throws {
        data.encode(key: codingPath + [key], value: "nil")
    }
    
    mutating func encode(_ value: Bool, forKey key: Key) throws {
        data.encode(key: codingPath + [key], value: value.description)
    }
    
    mutating func encode(_ value: String, forKey key: Key) throws {
        data.encode(key: codingPath + [key], value: value)
    }
    
    mutating func encode(_ value: Double, forKey key: Key) throws {
        data.encode(key: codingPath + [key], value: value.description)
    }
    
    mutating func encode(_ value: Float, forKey key: Key) throws {
        data.encode(key: codingPath + [key], value: value.description)
    }
    
    mutating func encode(_ value: Int, forKey key: Key) throws {
        data.encode(key: codingPath + [key], value: value.description)
    }
    
    mutating func encode(_ value: Int8, forKey key: Key) throws {
        data.encode(key: codingPath + [key], value: value.description)
    }
    
    mutating func encode(_ value: Int16, forKey key: Key) throws {
        data.encode(key: codingPath + [key], value: value.description)
    }
    
    mutating func encode(_ value: Int32, forKey key: Key) throws {
        data.encode(key: codingPath + [key], value: value.description)
    }
    
    mutating func encode(_ value: Int64, forKey key: Key) throws {
        data.encode(key: codingPath + [key], value: value.description)
    }
    
    mutating func encode(_ value: UInt, forKey key: Key) throws {
        data.encode(key: codingPath + [key], value: value.description)
    }
    
    mutating func encode(_ value: UInt8, forKey key: Key) throws {
        data.encode(key: codingPath + [key], value: value.description)
    }
    
    mutating func encode(_ value: UInt16, forKey key: Key) throws {
        data.encode(key: codingPath + [key], value: value.description)
    }
    
    mutating func encode(_ value: UInt32, forKey key: Key) throws {
        data.encode(key: codingPath + [key], value: value.description)
    }
    
    mutating func encode(_ value: UInt64, forKey key: Key) throws {
        data.encode(key: codingPath + [key], value: value.description)
    }
    
    mutating func encode<T: Encodable>(_ value: T, forKey key: Key) throws {
        var stringsEncoding = StringsEncoding(to: data)
        stringsEncoding.codingPath.append(key)
        try value.encode(to: stringsEncoding)
    }
    
    mutating func nestedContainer<NestedKey: CodingKey>(
        keyedBy keyType: NestedKey.Type,
        forKey key: Key) -> KeyedEncodingContainer<NestedKey> {
        var container = StringsKeyedEncoding<NestedKey>(to: data)
        container.codingPath = codingPath + [key]
        return KeyedEncodingContainer(container)
    }
    
    mutating func nestedUnkeyedContainer(forKey key: Key) -> UnkeyedEncodingContainer {
        var container = StringsUnkeyedEncoding(to: data)
        container.codingPath = codingPath + [key]
        return container
    }
    
    mutating func superEncoder() -> Encoder {
        let superKey = Key(stringValue: "super")!
        return superEncoder(forKey: superKey)
    }
    
    mutating func superEncoder(forKey key: Key) -> Encoder {
        var stringsEncoding = StringsEncoding(to: data)
        stringsEncoding.codingPath = codingPath + [key]
        return stringsEncoding
    }
}
```

```
fileprivate struct StringsUnkeyedEncoding: UnkeyedEncodingContainer {

    private let data: StringsEncoding.Data
    
    init(to data: StringsEncoding.Data) {
        self.data = data
    }
    
    var codingPath: [CodingKey] = []

    private(set) var count: Int = 0
    
    private mutating func nextIndexedKey() -> CodingKey {
        let nextCodingKey = IndexedCodingKey(intValue: count)!
        count += 1
        return nextCodingKey
    }
    
    private struct IndexedCodingKey: CodingKey {
        let intValue: Int?
        let stringValue: String

        init?(intValue: Int) {
            self.intValue = intValue
            self.stringValue = intValue.description
        }

        init?(stringValue: String) {
            return nil
        }
    }

    mutating func encodeNil() throws {
        data.encode(key: codingPath + [nextIndexedKey()], value: "nil")
    }
    
    mutating func encode(_ value: Bool) throws {
        data.encode(key: codingPath + [nextIndexedKey()], value: value.description)
    }
    
    mutating func encode(_ value: String) throws {
        data.encode(key: codingPath + [nextIndexedKey()], value: value)
    }
    
    mutating func encode(_ value: Double) throws {
        data.encode(key: codingPath + [nextIndexedKey()], value: value.description)
    }
    
    mutating func encode(_ value: Float) throws {
        data.encode(key: codingPath + [nextIndexedKey()], value: value.description)
    }
    
    mutating func encode(_ value: Int) throws {
        data.encode(key: codingPath + [nextIndexedKey()], value: value.description)
    }
    
    mutating func encode(_ value: Int8) throws {
        data.encode(key: codingPath + [nextIndexedKey()], value: value.description)
    }
    
    mutating func encode(_ value: Int16) throws {
        data.encode(key: codingPath + [nextIndexedKey()], value: value.description)
    }
    
    mutating func encode(_ value: Int32) throws {
        data.encode(key: codingPath + [nextIndexedKey()], value: value.description)
    }
    
    mutating func encode(_ value: Int64) throws {
        data.encode(key: codingPath + [nextIndexedKey()], value: value.description)
    }
    
    mutating func encode(_ value: UInt) throws {
        data.encode(key: codingPath + [nextIndexedKey()], value: value.description)
    }
    
    mutating func encode(_ value: UInt8) throws {
        data.encode(key: codingPath + [nextIndexedKey()], value: value.description)
    }
    
    mutating func encode(_ value: UInt16) throws {
        data.encode(key: codingPath + [nextIndexedKey()], value: value.description)
    }
    
    mutating func encode(_ value: UInt32) throws {
        data.encode(key: codingPath + [nextIndexedKey()], value: value.description)
    }
    
    mutating func encode(_ value: UInt64) throws {
        data.encode(key: codingPath + [nextIndexedKey()], value: value.description)
    }
    
    mutating func encode<T: Encodable>(_ value: T) throws {
        var stringsEncoding = StringsEncoding(to: data)
        stringsEncoding.codingPath = codingPath + [nextIndexedKey()]
        try value.encode(to: stringsEncoding)
    }
    
    mutating func nestedContainer<NestedKey: CodingKey>(
        keyedBy keyType: NestedKey.Type) -> KeyedEncodingContainer<NestedKey> {
        var container = StringsKeyedEncoding<NestedKey>(to: data)
        container.codingPath = codingPath + [nextIndexedKey()]
        return KeyedEncodingContainer(container)
    }
    
    mutating func nestedUnkeyedContainer() -> UnkeyedEncodingContainer {
        var container = StringsUnkeyedEncoding(to: data)
        container.codingPath = codingPath + [nextIndexedKey()]
        return container
    }
    
    mutating func superEncoder() -> Encoder {
        var stringsEncoding = StringsEncoding(to: data)
        stringsEncoding.codingPath.append(nextIndexedKey())
        return stringsEncoding
    }
}
```

```
fileprivate struct StringsSingleValueEncoding: SingleValueEncodingContainer {
    
    private let data: StringsEncoding.Data
    
    init(to data: StringsEncoding.Data) {
        self.data = data
    }

    var codingPath: [CodingKey] = []
    
    mutating func encodeNil() throws {
        data.encode(key: codingPath, value: "nil")
    }
    
    mutating func encode(_ value: Bool) throws {
        data.encode(key: codingPath, value: value.description)
    }
    
    mutating func encode(_ value: String) throws {
        data.encode(key: codingPath, value: value)
    }
    
    mutating func encode(_ value: Double) throws {
        data.encode(key: codingPath, value: value.description)
    }
    
    mutating func encode(_ value: Float) throws {
        data.encode(key: codingPath, value: value.description)
    }
    
    mutating func encode(_ value: Int) throws {
        data.encode(key: codingPath, value: value.description)
    }
    
    mutating func encode(_ value: Int8) throws {
        data.encode(key: codingPath, value: value.description)
    }
    
    mutating func encode(_ value: Int16) throws {
        data.encode(key: codingPath, value: value.description)
    }
    
    mutating func encode(_ value: Int32) throws {
        data.encode(key: codingPath, value: value.description)
    }
    
    mutating func encode(_ value: Int64) throws {
        data.encode(key: codingPath, value: value.description)
    }
    
    mutating func encode(_ value: UInt) throws {
        data.encode(key: codingPath, value: value.description)
    }
    
    mutating func encode(_ value: UInt8) throws {
        data.encode(key: codingPath, value: value.description)
    }
    
    mutating func encode(_ value: UInt16) throws {
        data.encode(key: codingPath, value: value.description)
    }
    
    mutating func encode(_ value: UInt32) throws {
        data.encode(key: codingPath, value: value.description)
    }
    
    mutating func encode(_ value: UInt64) throws {
        data.encode(key: codingPath, value: value.description)
    }
    
    mutating func encode<T: Encodable>(_ value: T) throws {
        var stringsEncoding = StringsEncoding(to: data)
        stringsEncoding.codingPath = codingPath
        try value.encode(to: stringsEncoding)
    }
}
```

Obviously, I made some design decisions regarding how to encode nested types using the (very!) simple *strings file* format. Hopefully, my code is clear enough that it should be easy to tweak the encoding details if so desired.

## Tests

A simple test for a trivial `Codable` type:

```
struct Product: Codable {
    var name: String
    var price: Float
    var info: String
}

let iPhone = Product(name: "iPhone X", price: 1_000, info: "Our best iPhone yet!")

let stringsEncoder = StringsEncoder()
do {
    let stringsFile = try stringsEncoder.encode(iPhone)
    print(stringsFile)
} catch {
    print("Encoding failed: \(error)")
}
```

Output:

```
/* Generated by StringsEncoder */
"info" = "Our best iPhone yet!";
"name" = "iPhone X";
"price" = "1000.0";
```

A more complex test with *nested structs* and *arrays*:

```
struct Product: Codable {
    var name: String
    var price: Float
    var info: String
}

struct Address: Codable {
    var street: String
    var city: String
    var state: String
}

struct Store: Codable {
    var name: String
    var address: Address // nested struct
    var products: [Product] // array
}

let iPhone = Product(name: "iPhone X", price: 1_000, info: "Our best iPhone yet!")
let macBook = Product(name: "Mac Book Pro", price: 2_000, info: "Early 2019")
let watch = Product(name: "Apple Watch", price: 500, info: "Series 4")

let appleStore = Store(
    name: "Apple Store",
    address: Address(street: "300 Post Street", city: "San Francisco", state: "CA"),
    products: [iPhone, macBook, watch]
)

let stringsEncoder = StringsEncoder()
do {
    let stringsFile = try stringsEncoder.encode(appleStore)
    print(stringsFile)
} catch {
    print("Encoding failed: \(error)")
}
```

Output:

```
/* Generated by StringsEncoder */
"address.city" = "San Francisco";
"address.state" = "CA";
"address.street" = "300 Post Street";
"name" = "Apple Store";
"products.0.info" = "Our best iPhone yet!";
"products.0.name" = "iPhone X";
"products.0.price" = "1000.0";
"products.1.info" = "Early 2019";
"products.1.name" = "Mac Book Pro";
"products.1.price" = "2000.0";
"products.2.info" = "Series 4";
"products.2.name" = "Apple Watch";
"products.2.price" = "500.0";
```

## Decoding

Given how big this answer already is, I'm gonna to leave the **decoding** part (i.e., creating the `StringsDecoder` class, conforming to the `Decoder` protocol, etc) as an exercise to the reader... please let me know if you guys need any help with that and I will post a complete solution later ;)

Comment: this is brilliant. Any suggestions on how to add custom Date format  encoding?

Comment: Also to note, `String(describing:)` should be used instead of `.description`

Comment: @Patrick Thanks ;) You could add a custom `Date` formatting in the method that encodes an `Encodable` object (i.e., check `value is Date`). You would then convert the `Date` to string—that’s your custom date formatting!—and then finally call `encode(to:)` on that. You would need to add this logic in the three containers types to cover all `Date` usages. Finally, be sure to also check `JSONEncoder.DateEncodingStrategy` for a nice way to expose date formatting as an extensible API for your encoder.

Comment: So are you distantly related to Donald Knuth?  For a personal project I'm writing a parser for mail headers. As an exercise in learning more I would like to use Decodable. I know I could easily do this in other ways but as I said I'd like to lean to do this with Decodable. I think I understand the usual things that are described in articles talking about custom types using JSONDecode but I don't understand the part that JSONDeocde does?

Comment: Wouldn't naming the private class Data be an issue for custom Encoders where the output format is the basic Data type ?

Comment: I have a question : Inside your ```SingleValueContainer```, when encode receives a ```Codable``` object of an unknown type, it doesn't mutate it's own ```strings`` at all. Isn't the data lost then ? Or am I missing something ?