# Swift: Background upload using URLSession

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-s3, urlsession, nsurlsessionuploadtask

I'm trying to upload files to the s3 bucket using URLSession. I understood that to upload files in the background, I need to use `uploadTask(with:fromFile:)` method as mentioned [here](https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/urlsession-common-pitfalls-with-background-download-upload-tasks/#3-only-urlsession-upload-tasks-from-a-file-support-background-execution). So I am performing below steps to upload the file.

1. Create a background URLSession

```swift
lazy var session: URLSession = {
                let bundleIdentifier = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!
                let config = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: bundleIdentifier + ".background")
                config.sharedContainerIdentifier = bundleIdentifier
                config.sessionSendsLaunchEvents = true
                return URLSession(configuration: config, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
            }()
```

2. Generate request with [multipart](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2) data

Data Model

```swift
struct UploadRequest {
    let destinationUrl: URL
    let sourceURL: URL
    let params: [String: String]
    let fileName: String
    let mimeType: String
}
```

```swift
private func requestAndPath(for
                                uploadParam: UploadRequest) -> (request: URLRequest,
                                                                filePath: URL)? {

        // Create an empty file and append header, file content and footer to it
        let uuid = UUID().uuidString
        let directoryURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .cachesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
        let fileURL = directoryURL.appendingPathComponent(uuid)
        let filePath = fileURL.path
        FileManager.default.createFile(atPath: filePath, contents: nil, attributes: nil)
        let file = FileHandle(forWritingAtPath: filePath)!

        let boundary = UUID().uuidString
        let newline = "\r\n"

        do {
            let partName = "file"
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: uploadParam.sourceURL)
            // Write boundary header
            var header = ""
            header += "--\(boundary)" + newline
            header += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(partName)\"; filename=\"\(uploadParam.fileName)\"" + newline
            for (key, value) in uploadParam.params {
                header += "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)" + newline
                header += newline
                header += value + newline
            }
            
            header += "Content-Type: \(uploadParam.mimeType)" + newline
            header += newline

            let headerData = header.data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)
            // Write data
            file.write(headerData!)
            file.write(data)

            // Write boundary footer
            var footer = ""
            footer += newline
            footer += "--\(boundary)--" + newline
            footer += newline

            let footerData = footer.data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)
            file.write(footerData!)
            file.closeFile()

            let contentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)"
            var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: uploadParam.destinationUrl)
            urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
            urlRequest.setValue(contentType, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            return (urlRequest, fileURL)
        } catch {
            debugPrint("Error generating url request")
        }
        return nil
    }
```

3. Upload file

```swift
func uploadFile(request: UploadRequest) {
       if let reqPath = requestAndPath(for: uploadRequest) {
            let task = session.uploadTask(with: reqPath.request,
                                          fromFile: reqPath.filePath)
            task.resume()
        }
}
```

When I call the `uploadFile` method, the delegate `didSendBodyData` is called once and the control goes to `didCompleteWithError` with error as nil. But the file is not uploaded to the s3 bucket. What could be the issue?

I am able to upload the file using Alamofire but since Alamofire [doesn't support background upload](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/2721#issuecomment-464822707), I would like to fallback to URLSession

Upload using Alamofire (default)

```swift
AF.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
            for (key, value) in uploadRequest.params {
                if let data = value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false) {
                    multipartFormData.append(data, withName: key)
                }
            }
            multipartFormData.append(
                uploadRequest.sourceURL,
                withName: "File",
                fileName: uploadRequest.fileName,
                mimeType: uploadRequest.mimeType
            )
        }, with: urlRequest).responseData { response in
            if let responseData = response.data {
                let strData = String(decoding: responseData, as: UTF8.self)
                debugPrint("Response data \(strData)")
            } else {
                debugPrint("Error is \(response.error)")
            }
        }.uploadProgress { progress in
            debugPrint("Progress \(progress)")
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made changes in the request body and wrote the data to the file and used `uploadTask(with:fromFile:)` method using the background session. `urlSessionDidFinishEvents(forBackgroundURLSession:)` will be called once the upload is completed when the app is in the background.

```swift
private func requestAndPath(for
                                uploadParam: UploadRequest) -> (request: URLRequest,
                                                                filePath: URL)? {
        
        let uuid = UUID().uuidString
        let directoryURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .cachesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
        let fileURL = directoryURL.appendingPathComponent(uuid)
        let filePath = fileURL.path
        FileManager.default.createFile(atPath: filePath, contents: nil, attributes: nil)
        let file = FileHandle(forWritingAtPath: filePath)!
        
        let boundary = generateBoundary()
        let lineBreak = "\r\n"
        var body = Data()

        for (key, value) in uploadParam.params {
            body.append("--\(boundary + lineBreak)")
            body.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\(lineBreak + lineBreak)")
            body.append("\(value + lineBreak)")
        }
        
        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: uploadParam.sourceURL)
            body.append("--\(boundary + lineBreak)")
            body.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"File\"; filename=\"\(uploadParam.fileName)\"\(lineBreak)")
            body.append("Content-Type: \(uploadParam.mimeType + lineBreak + lineBreak)")
            body.append(data)
            body.append(lineBreak)
            body.append("--\(boundary)--\(lineBreak)")
            file.write(body)
            file.closeFile()
            
            var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: uploadParam.destinationUrl)
            urlRequest.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
            return (urlRequest, fileURL)
        } catch {
            debugPrint("Error getting request")
        }
        return nil
    } 


func generateBoundary() -> String {
        return UUID().uuidString
    }


extension Data {
    mutating func append(_ string: String) {
    if let data = string.data(using: .utf8) {
      self.append(data)
    }
  }
}
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58246456/696465