# How does the encoded data end up in the Encoder, when it has no mutating functions?

Tags: swift, encoding

I am trying to code a custom `Coder` and I am having trouble understanding something, particularly about the `Encoder` part.

The `Encoder` is only required to have three functions and two variables :

```swift
struct MyEncoder : Encoder {
    public var codingPath : [CodingKey]
    public var userInfo : [CodingUserInfoKey : Any]
    public func container<Key>(keyedBy type: Key.Type -> KeyedEncodingContainer<Key> where Key : CodingKey {}
    public func unkeyedContainer() -> UnkeyedEncodingContainer {}
    public func singleValueContainer() -> SingleValueEncodingContainer {}
}
```

You will notice, none of them are mutating. They all return something and that's it.

The containers themselves, to generalise, have sub functions to encode specific types into themselves :

```swift
struct MySingleValueContainer : SingleValueEncodingContainer {
    var codingPath: [CodingKey]
    mutating func encode(_ value : someType) throws {}
    /// etc with a lot of different types
}
```

If a user wants to customise how their class is encoded, they may do this :

```swift
func encode(to: Encoder) throws {}
```

And here is my problem ! The encoder persists after the call to `encode(to: Encoder)` but it **does not mutate** so how does the encoded data end up inside it ? Reading the [JSON Encoder's source](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/ac78023955e62c003f6ac02e75257afaa1ee8d07/Sources/Foundation/JSONEncoder.swift) I can see that their containers have a variable containing an `Encoder`, which is passed down. But it should be copy-on-write as everything else in Swift, which means the data shouldn't be able to make its way back up the chain !

Is the `Encoder` somehow secretly passed as a reference instead of as a value ? That seems like the only logical conclusion but it seems *very weird* to me... If not, what is going on ?

---

I have also taken a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45169254/custom-swift-encoder-decoder-for-the-strings-resource-format) and its answer, and although they have helped me they display the same behaviour of magically bringing data up the chain, except it passes down a custom type instead of the `Encoder` itself.

Comment: Let me ask you (just in case you have this misunderstanding), in the case of `JSONEncoder`, which concrete implementation of `Encoder` does it use? (Note that `JSONEncoder` does not conform to `Encoder`)

Comment: @LeoDabus if you read the last paragraph, I have mentioned this question and explained why it doesn’t help for this particular problem

Comment: @Sweeper the JSONEncoder uses JSONEncoderImpl which does conform to the protocol

Comment: So what exactly are you confused about? `JSONEncoderImpl` is a class, so it is always pass by reference anyway...?

Comment: @Crysambrosia ops my bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the `Encoder` somehow secretly passed as a reference instead of as a value?

Close, but not quite. `JSONEncoder` and its underlying containers are relatively thin veneer interfaces for *reference-based* storage. In the swift-corelibs-foundation implementation used on non-Darwin platforms, this is done using [`RefArray`](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/ac78023955e62c003f6ac02e75257afaa1ee8d07/Sources/Foundation/JSONEncoder.swift#L252) and [`RefObject`](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/ac78023955e62c003f6ac02e75257afaa1ee8d07/Sources/Foundation/JSONEncoder.swift#L295) to store keyed objects; on Darwin platforms, the same is done using [`NSMutableArray`](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/3d1c1ad39b69aa994b52671209936e81ab28b6fd/Darwin/Foundation-swiftoverlay/JSONEncoder.swift#L342) and [`NSMutableDictionary`](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/3d1c1ad39b69aa994b52671209936e81ab28b6fd/Darwin/Foundation-swiftoverlay/JSONEncoder.swift#L324). It's *these* reference objects that are passed around and shared, so while the individual `Encoder`s and containers can be passed around, they're writing to shared storage.

> But it should be copy-on-write as everything else in Swift, which means the data shouldn't be able to make its way back up the chain!

One more note on this: all of the relevant types internal to this implementation are all classes (e.g. [`JSONEncoderImpl`](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/ac78023955e62c003f6ac02e75257afaa1ee8d07/Sources/Foundation/JSONEncoder.swift#L366) in swift-corelibs-foundation, [`_JSONEncoder`](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/3d1c1ad39b69aa994b52671209936e81ab28b6fd/Darwin/Foundation-swiftoverlay/JSONEncoder.swift#L282) on Darwin), which means that they *wouldn't* be copy-on-write, but rather, passed by reference anyway.

---

Regarding your edit: this is the same approach that the [linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54612620/169394) uses with its `fileprivate final class Data` — it's that *class* which is shared between all of the internal types and passed around.

Comment: As an addition to this, you may find the [Flight School Guide to Swift Codable](https://flight.school/books/codable/) useful — it contains a pretty good walkthrough of how to write a basic `Encoder` and might help illuminate a few things.

Comment: Thank you ! I had completely forgotten that classes are passed as reference. It completely makes sense now, I think I’m actually going to be able to finish my custom one. Definitely will take a look at what you linked also, resources about this topic are surprisingly rare.

Answer (score 0):

`JSONEncoder.encode` uses `JSONEncoderImpl` as the concrete implementation of `Encoder` ([source](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/ac78023955e62c003f6ac02e75257afaa1ee8d07/Sources/Foundation/JSONEncoder.swift#L226)):

```
open func encode<T: Encodable>(_ value: T) throws -> Data {
    let value: JSONValue = try encodeAsJSONValue(value)
    ...
}

func encodeAsJSONValue<T: Encodable>(_ value: T) throws -> JSONValue {
    let encoder = JSONEncoderImpl(options: self.options, codingPath: [])
    guard let topLevel = try encoder.wrapEncodable(value, for: nil) else {
        ...
    }

    return topLevel
}
```

`wrapEncodable` would then eventually call `encode(to: Encoder)` on your `Codable` type with `self` as the argument.

> Is the `Encoder` somehow secretly passed as a reference instead of as a value ?

Notice that `JSONEncoderImpl` is a class, so there is nothing "secret" about this at all. The encoder *is* passed as a reference in this particular case.

In general though, the `Encoder` implementation could also be a `struct`, and be passed by value. After all, all it needs to do is to provide mutable containers into which data can be encoded. As long as you have a class *somewhere* down the line, it is possible to "seemingly" mutate a struct without `mutating` or making the struct a `var`. Consider:

```
private class Bar {
    var magic: Int = -1
}

struct Foo: CustomStringConvertible {
    private let bar = Bar()
    
    var description: String { "\(bar.magic)" }
    
    func magicallyMutateMyself() {
        bar.magic = Int.random(in: 0..<100)
    }
}

let foo = Foo()
print(foo) // -1
foo.magicallyMutateMyself()
print(foo) // some other number
```