# What is superEncoder for in UnkeyedEncodingContainer and KeyedEncodingContainerProtocol?

Tags: swift, encoding

I'm sorry to ask such a basic question but I haven't been able to find the answer anywhere :

In order to make an `Encoder`, you must define different types of containers :

- `SingleValueEncodingContainer`
- `UnkeyedEncodingContainer`
- `KeyedEncodingContainerProtocol` (*yes the naming spec is weird*)

Those last two must both contain a method called `superEncoder` however I have not been able to find what it's supposed to do anywhere. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45169254/custom-swift-encoder-decoder-for-the-strings-resource-format) has an answer that implements it but doesn't explain it, and [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yL5Ff5p1hyc) only makes a passing mention of it.

What is it supposed to do, and what is it for ?

Comment: `superEncoder` is for supporting inheritance in `Encodable` **classes**.

Comment: @vadian can you describe how it is used ? I'm unsure what kind of information it needs. Is it fine to just return a new encoder or do I have to maintain state from the container that contains it ? (*That would be an issue since I currently use different internal storages in each type of container, and unifying them doesn't currently seem possible*)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`superEncoder` in encoders and `superDecoder` in decoders is a way to be able to "reserve" a nested container inside of a container, without knowing what type it will be ahead of time.

One of the main purposes for this is to support inheritance in `Encodable`/`Decodable` classes: a class `T: Encodable` may choose to encode its contents into an `UnkeyedContainer`, but its subclass `U: T` may choose to encode its contents into a `KeyedContainer`.

In `U.encode(to:)`, `U` will need to call `super.encode(to:)`, and pass in an `Encoder` — but it cannot pass in the `Encoder` that it has received, because it has already encoded its contents in a keyed way, and it is invalid for `T` to request an unkeyed container from that `Encoder`. (And in general, `U` won't even know what kind of container `T` might want.)

The escape hatch, then, is for `U` to ask its container for a nested *`Encoder`* to be able to pass that along to its superclass. The container will make space for a nested value and create a new `Encoder` which allows for writing into that reserved space. `T` can then use that nested `Encoder` to encode however it would like.

The result ends up looking as if `U` requested a nested container and encoded the values of `T` into it.

---

To make this a bit more concrete, consider the following:

```swift
import Foundation

class T: Encodable {
    let x, y: Int
    init(x: Int, y: Int) { self.x = x; self.y = y }
    
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.unkeyedContainer()
        try container.encode(x)
        try container.encode(y)
    }
}

class U: T {
    let z: Int
    init(x: Int, y: Int, z: Int) { self.z = z; super.init(x: x, y: y) }
    
    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey { case z }
    
    override func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(z, forKey: .z)
        
        /* How to encode T.x and T.y? */
    }
}

let u = U(x: 1, y: 2, z: 3)
let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(u)
print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8))
```

`U` has a few options for how to encode `x` and `y`:

1. It can truly override the encoding policy of `T` by including `x` and `y` in its `CodingKeys` enum and encode them directly. This ignores how `T` would prefer to encode, and if *decoding* is required, means that you'll have to be able to create a new `T` *without* calling its `init(from:)`
2. It can call `super.encode(to: encoder)` to have the superclass encode into the *same* encoder that it does. In this case, this will **crash**, since `U` has already requested a keyed container from `encoder`, and calling `T.encode(to:)` will immediately request an unkeyed container from the same encoder

   - In general, this *may* work if `T` and `U` both request the same container type, but it's really not recommended to rely on. Depending on how `T` encodes, it may override values that `U` has already encoded
3. Nest `T` *inside* of the keyed container with `super.encode(to: container.superEncoder())`; this will reserve a spot in the container dictionary, create a new `Encoder`, and have `T` write to that encoder. The result of this, in JSON, will be:

   ```json
   { "z": 3,
     "super": [1, 2] }
   ```

Comment: So I would have to make my ```EncodingContainer``` able to store an ```Encoder```, and then ask for its encoded data when the "real" encoding step actually happens. Is that correct ?

Comment: @Crysambrosia It depends entirely on how the rest of your `Encoder` is written. For instance, `JSONEncoder` [returns a new `Encoder` type which _references_ the original `Encoder`](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/3d1c1ad39b69aa994b52671209936e81ab28b6fd/Darwin/Foundation-swiftoverlay/JSONEncoder.swift#L546) (and basically keeps track of where it was requested to write to), and [on `deinit`](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/3d1c1ad39b69aa994b52671209936e81ab28b6fd/Darwin/Foundation-swiftoverlay/JSONEncoder.swift#L1010) actually does the writing

Comment: One more detail : Why does ```KeyedEncodingContainerProtocol``` have a ```superEncoder``` method **without** a key ? What am I supposed to do with that one ?

Comment: @Crysambrosia `superEncoder()` is ["Equivalent to calling `superEncoder(forKey:)` with `Key(stringValue: "super", intValue: 0)`."](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/keyedencodingcontainerprotocol/2893423-superencoder#discussion), i.e., it encodes as if the `CodingKey` enum being used has a `super` key, and uses that key.

Comment: `JSONEncoder`, for instance, has an internal [`_JSONKey` struct](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/3d1c1ad39b69aa994b52671209936e81ab28b6fd/Darwin/Foundation-swiftoverlay/JSONEncoder.swift#L2520) as a utility for various internal uses, and has a convenience [`super` key](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/3d1c1ad39b69aa994b52671209936e81ab28b6fd/Darwin/Foundation-swiftoverlay/JSONEncoder.swift#L2544) it uses for this purpose

Comment: Thank you ! Since it is equivalent I have just made it call the other version with ```CodingKey(stringValue: "super")``` as a key, so I don't write the same logic twice.

Comment: @Crysambrosia Note that the other method needs to be generic on the original `CodingKey` type, which might not have a meaningful value for the string `super` (e.g., if it's an enum, `Key.init(stringValue: "super")` may return `nil`); that's why `JSONEncoder.superEncoder()` duplicates the method instead of calling the key version.

Comment: What if there is no nested data? What to do with `superEncoder` etc?

Comment: @koen That's up to the `Encoder` to decide — it may decide to encode an empty container, or skip encoding anything.

Comment: (The important thing is that decoding remain valid in that case; it's more common, and probably recommended, to encode an empty container if `super` doesn't end up writing any nested data.)